# Does "xl" mean anything special in php?

Tags: php

I am reading some php code and not sure what "xl" means here:

```
$ISSUE_TYPE_STYLES = array(
  0 => xl('Standard'),                    
  1 => xl('Simplified')                 
);
```

I am not exactly sure what "xl" means here. Does it mean anything special? Or is it possible that this is a variable from another php file? I don't see any "include" or "require" in the php file that I am reading though.

Comment: It's a function that must have been defined somewhere else. It's not part of PHP's core functions.

Comment: Adding on to Pekka, if you don't see any require or include, look at PHPs auto_prepend_file config directive, as that can be including a file without you knowing about it.

Comment: @Kyle More probable is that this file is included from somewhere else.

Comment: thanks guys. Was able to find this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `xl` is a function. If you use IDE you could try to CTRL + LClick on the `xl` or you could search something like `function xl(` to find this function.

Comment: Thanks tuchk4. Since I am not using an IDE with the whole project available, I did a quick search of "function xl" and did find this function in installer.class.php:  function xl($s) { return $s; }    Looks like this is nothing but return the input itself. So technically I can define the array as "0" => "Standard" instead of xl("Standard"), right? Not sure why the code is written with a "useless" xl function.

Comment: yes. you are right. But what the application or what framework or CMS is used where such "usefull" functions are used :)

Answer (score 2):

It's function, if you use any IDE, e.g. Netbeans you can load whole project, press ctrl and click on its name, it will redirect you to declaration

Answer (score 1):

xl("word") calls a function that will translate the contents, e.g.,"word" into the language selected in the program (native).  For example, this allows someone running the program in German to see it as "wort" (the German translation).